# Travis Build is Stuck on Building fresh packages step

Tags: next.js, travis-ci, yarnpkg, node-sass, travis-ci-cli

My build for a react-nextjs application was working properly till a few days ago. But for some reason, deployments are stuck on the `Building fresh packages` step. We use yarn.

And I checked the logs via debug mode of Travis. I followed these steps to see some logs about the issue. https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5129#issuecomment-842775713

And I see an `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` error.
[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve that issue?

Comment: Somehow yarn & Travis didn't run `yarn install` We were using node-sass and sharp library. (Sharp is optional library from next library. As a solution, we migrated node-sass to sass and removed optional library installations. For now we fixed our stuck issue and deployments are running again.

Comment: You may want to add the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question. This indicates the question has already been answered.

Comment: I think our solution is just a workaround. Still, we don't know why Travis and yarn was stuck because of that libraries. So, I prefer not to add our fix as a solution. But thanks for the suggestion.